# docker run hello-world not working after eval $(minikube docker-env)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, sbt, minikube

I am trying to do `docker:publishLocal` from sbt after performing

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

so that it gets build in kubernetes itself but running that cmd it gives:

```
[warn]           
[success] All package validations passed
[info] Sending build context to Docker daemon  185.1MB
[info] Step 1/16 : FROM openjdk:8 as stage0
[error] Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:483)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$33(DockerPlugin.scala:187)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$33$adapted(DockerPlugin.scala:185)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (Docker / publishLocal) Nonzero exit value: 1
[error] Total time: 164 s, completed 5 Mar, 2021 1:56:16 PM
```

So. I tested :

```
 docker run hello-world
```

which gave:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

then I tried restarting followed by:

```
docker logout
docker login
....
    error during connect: Post https://192.168.49.2:2376/v1.24/auth: dial tcp 192.168.49.2:2376: connect: no route to host
```

Now on

```
docker run hello-world

docker: error during connect: Post https://192.168.49.2:2376/v1.24/containers/create: dial tcp 192.168.49.2:2376: connect: no route to host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

So, How can I do publishLocal into the kubernetes itself or run hello-world if everything is fine after `eval $(minikube docker-env)` ?

Comment: This just indicates that your VM has no access to the internet for the some reason. Check why is that

Comment: @TarunLalwani , but then for publishLocal , any resolution to that

Comment: Which OS and Virtual software are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and have installed minikube through
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Comment: Do a `minikube ssh` and then `ping google.com` see if you are able to reach internet or not. If it doesn't work then run the command `sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf` and see if fixes the issue?

Comment: not able to add nameserver in resolv.conf, it keeps blinking and gets resetted and also trying it, my internet stops working @TarunLalwani

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` on your host machine?

Comment: nameserver 10.11.0.40 
nameserver 10.11.0.41 with line breaks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229573/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-supernatural).

Comment: Which minikube driver are you using ?

Comment: minikube version: v1.18.1
@matt_j

Comment: yes but I asked about [minikube driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/).